# What does "es" mean here?

Tags: meaning, pronoun

The following is from Kafka's *Der Proceß*:

> Ich gehe über meinen Auftrag hinaus, wenn ich Ihnen so freundschaftlich zurede. Aber ich hoffe, **es** hört **es** niemand sonst als Franz, und der ist selbst gegen alle Vorschrift freundlich zu Ihnen.

I'm not sure of the usage of the bold *es*. I guess either of them (most probably the second) refers to the talking (to the protagonist K = *Ihnen*) by the speaker, but what about the other one? Can *es* mean *dass*?

Comment: It means literally nothing, much like the "there" in "There is no one else listening" does not means any place at all.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50360/es-waren-dies-jene-neuesten-telephone-from-der-verschollene-by-kafka

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can boil it down to this sentence:

> Es hört es sonst niemand als Franz.

I'll begin to explain the first *»es«,* but you should know, that the second *»es«* can be replaced by *»das«* (details below). So we also can analyze this sentence:

> Es hört das sonst niemand als Franz.

The first *»es«* is an expletive pronoun who's only function is to fill a position in a sentence that otherwise would be empty. Like in these examples:

> Leute sitzen im Lokal. = **Es** sitzen Leute im Lokal.
> Ein Zug fährt nach nirgendwo. = **Es** fährt ein Zug nach nirgendwo.

In both examples the subject (*»Leute«, »ein Zug«*) has been moved away from position 1 without moving any other part of speech to position 1 instead. But because it can't stay empty, a fill-word without any meaning is placed there, and this filler is the expletive pronoun *»es«.*

And the same happens in Kafka's sentence:

> Es/das hört sonst niemand als Franz. = **Es** hört es/das sonst niemand als Franz.

---

Now about the second *»es«:* This is a personal pronoun in accusative case that refers to something that was mentioned before and that is heard by nobody but Franz in the sentence of interest. But you can also refer to what is heard with a demonstrative pronoun in accusative case. And so you can use *»das«* instead of *»es«*

All these sentences mean the same:

> Das hört sonst niemand als Franz.
> Es hört sonst niemand als Franz.
> Es hört das sonst niemand als Franz.
> Es hört es sonst niemand als Franz.